# Three.JS updating camera breaks shader?

Tags: javascript, html, three.js, shader

I'm copying the Bubble shader from https://github.com/stemkoski/stemkoski.github.com/blob/master/Three.js/Bubble.html yet the code is out of date, and where the example refracts whatever is behind it:

[image]

Mine is black. The warning I get (and where problem is I believe) in animate():

```
animate() {
    this.controls.update();

    this.renderer.render(this.scene, this.camera);

    this.sphere.visible = false;
    //this.refractSphereCamera.updateCubeMap( this.renderer, this.scene );
    this.refractSphereCamera.update();
    this.sphere.visible = true;

    //this.renderer.render( this.scene, this.camera );
    requestAnimationFrame(this.animate.bind(this));
  }
```

This `this.refractSphereCamera.updateCubeMap( this.renderer, this.scene );` is the original line where console gives me:

> THREE.CubeCamera: .updateCubeMap() is now .update().

Here is the actual shader/sphere:

```
this.refractSphereCamera = new THREE.CubeCamera( 0.1, 5000, 512 );
    this.scene.add( this.refractSphereCamera );

    var fShader = THREE.FresnelShader;

    var fresnelUniforms =
    {
        "mRefractionRatio": { type: "f", value: 1.02 },
        "mFresnelBias":     { type: "f", value: 0.1 },
        "mFresnelPower":    { type: "f", value: 2.0 },
        "mFresnelScale":    { type: "f", value: 1.0 },
        "tCube":            { type: "t", value: this.refractSphereCamera.renderTarget } //textureCube
    };

    // create custom material for the shader
    var customMaterial = new THREE.ShaderMaterial(
    {
        uniforms:       fresnelUniforms,
        vertexShader:   fShader.vertexShader,
        fragmentShader: fShader.fragmentShader
    }   );

    var sphereGeometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry( 100, 64, 32 );
    this.sphere = new THREE.Mesh( sphereGeometry, customMaterial);
    this.sphere.position.set(0, 50, 100);
    this.scene.add(this.sphere);

    this.refractSphereCamera.position.set(this.sphere.position);
```

I can feed a textureCube into the shader and it works, but I want not just the skybox but all objects behind the sphere to refract. What is wrong here?

Everything goes black if I change to .update()

Other warning is:

> THREE.WebGLRenderer.setTextureCube: don't use cube render targets as
>   textures. Use their .texture property instead.

Comment: Can you post some working code? nothing seems like it's wrong here, but its not shown how are you rendering the background. For a sanity check, could you turn off your skybox, and clear the background to something not black, and render a plane?

Comment: http://stemkoski.github.io/Three.js/Bubble.html - this is the working one. I did that - it doesn't render any objects behind it in the refraction if I feed in a texture cube, and black otherwise. But see the error I also get above

Answer (score 0):

Try increasing your `.far` to 5,001, or 10,000. The example seems to be rendering the skybox as a cube inside the scene, if your camera clips at 5,000 and the cube is of the same size, it may very well be that it's simply clipped behind your camera.

Comment: Nope, tried that and still black.If its relevant I also get the error posted above - THREE.WebGLRenderer.setTextureCube: don't use cube render targets as textures. Use their .texture property instead.

Comment: that one i think shouldnt matter as much, since it automagically falls back, but maybe that changed (you can try providing `.texture`). As ive said in the other comment, clearing the background and rendering a plane into a cubemap would be a good step at debugging this because you take the skybox out of the equation. If you can reflect some 3d objects, and a custom color background, you can move onto trying to render the skybox...

Comment: Ive tried putting other objects in back of the sphere, as well as a floor, and the sphere remains entirely black. What would you suggest next, code wise?

Comment: `renderer.setClearColor( 0xff0000, 1)`

Comment: Also possible that this needs to be called manually in recent versions: https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/renderers/WebGLRenderer.setRenderTarget

In addition to this, you can verify if the shader even works, by loading a cube texture (not rendering to one).

Comment: it is still black even clearing it. The shader does work because as I said above, feeding in a texture cube works. How would I install a renderer manually? What does that entail?

Comment: I get 'Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'render' of undefined' when I try to update the refraction camera in any way